# Is there any way to check whether a file exists on another server with PHP?

Tags: php

I tried is_file(), but seems it could not check remote files. 
I need to check whether a bookcover image is there on my image server and if it does not exists i'll use another one instead. What's the alternative way to do this except is_file?

Answer (score 2):

you could try to retrieve it with `curl` and check if you get a 404 or an actual hit?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
if (getimagesize($url))
    echo "An image found!"
```

As [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) will check return the size of an image, an false on failure.

Comment: @yi_H According to the documentation, getimagesize supports urls (there is an example with an global url), and is_file() only supports some url wrappers in the newer versions. Also OP asked about images, which getimagesize will support, where is_file will maybe return true on 404 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
 function fileExists($path){
    return (@fopen($path,"r")==true);
  }
```

Or I use this function on my website to check if image links are valid/still exists. This is better because its specific for images. It's also with fopen though.

```
    function isImage($url)
{
 $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'HEAD'
           ));
 $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
 $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
 if (!$fp) 
    return false;  // Problem with url

$meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
if ($meta === false)
{
    fclose($fp);
    return false;  // Problem reading data from url
}
```